# pytorch 3d tensor slicing with list works only if there is one value or one True value in list

Tags: pytorch, slice, tensor, masking

I have a 3d tensor that I want to mask out row-wise using `row_mask`. Whether a row is to be masked depends on a boolean list, with a True value corresponding to the row to be masked. The code below works as expected when there is one True in the list, but gives an IndexError when there are two True's and gives an unexpected output when there are three True's. Could someone point to a solution or explain the behavior for two and three True's?

```
x = torch.arange(24).reshape(4,1,6).float()
row_mask = [1,2,5]
app_mask = [False,True,False,False]    # apply row_mask in 1st row only
x[app_mask,-1,row_mask] = -float('inf')
print(x[:,-1,:])
```

```
tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6., -inf, -inf,  9., 10., -inf],
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
        [18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.]])
```

For two True's,

```
x = torch.arange(24).reshape(4,1,6).float()
row_mask = [1,2,5]
app_mask2 = [False,True,True,False]    # apply row_mask in 1st and 2nd rows
x[app_mask2,-1,row_mask] = -float('inf')
```

I get this:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing tensors could not be broadcast together with shapes [2], [3]
```

For three True's,

```
x = torch.arange(24).reshape(4,1,6).float()
row_mask = [1,2,5]
app_mask3 = [False,True,True,True]    # apply row_mask to 1st, 2nd, and 3rd rows
x[app_mask3,-1,row_mask] = -float('inf')
```

I get this unexpected result, which changed rows 1, 2, and 3 but not in the way I expected.

```
tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6., -inf,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., -inf, 15., 16., 17.],
        [18., 19., 20., 21., 22., -inf]])
```

Apart from Booleans, `x[[1],-1,row_mask] = -float('inf')` works to reassign the 1st row, but `x[[0,1],-1,row_mask] = -float('inf')` doesn't work to reassign the 0th and 1st row. So what is it about indexing multiple rows of a 3d tensor that is the problem and how can I work around it?